# What does the xticks in pd.plot really means? pd.plot(x,y,xticks)

Tags: python, pandas

```py
oil_price = pd.read_csv("2018-2019.csv",usecols=["date","brent"])    
oil_price.info() # now the type of "date" is object.
oil_price["date"] = pd.to_datetime(oil_price["date"]) # now the type of    "date" is datetime64.
oil_price_2018 = oil_price.loc[(oil_price["date"]>"2018-1-1") &    (oil_price["date"]<"2018-12-30")] 
oil_price_2018.info() # now the type of "date" is datetime64.
oil_price_2018.plot(x="date",y="brent",figsize=(60,5),rot=-90,grid=True,xticks=oil_price_2018["date"])
```

before i changed the datatype of "date into datetime64, i can use the `df.plot(** xticks=range(105))` to plot the dataframe.
but after i changed the datatype of "date" into datetime64, when i use the `xticks=range(105)` there is error:
DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with `ax.xaxis_date()`
so i have to change this parameter as `xticks = oil_price_2018["date"]`
Any one is willing help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create figure and plot space
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    
# Add x-axis and y-axis
ax.bar(df.index.values,
           df['bret'],
            color='purple')
    
 # Set title and labels for axes
ax.set(xlabel="Date",
           ylabel="bret",
           title="Some title")
    
 # Rotate tick marks on x-axis
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
        
 plt.show()
```